# Inkscape prints my image shifted to right

Tags: printing, inkscape

I have created a page with three warnings:

[image: Warnings: oxidising, dangerous and corrosive]

However, when I print it in inkscape, this appears:

[image]

So what's going on? [Here's the original file](http://pastebin.com/YyUkw7Vp) as I created it:.

Comment: How does the right border look like? Anyway, this might be due to additional margins used by Inkscape or some printer interface to avoid parts of the image not being printed. The easiest way to deal with this is arguably to export the image as a PDF and print that as PDF programs tend to have the best printer settings.

Comment: There's no right border. The second image is scanned paper as I got it from printer, with added black frame using GIMP.

Comment: Ah, I thought it was only an excerpt of the left part. I am afraid, I am out of ideas then.